# why `rsync --sparse` create much larger file than the source?

Tags: rsync, sparse-files

I try to rsync between 2 local disks, thus there is no compression. the sparse file has apparent size of 50GB, actual size of 16GB. I tried `rsync -a -P --sparse`, it did generate sparse file on destination at the end. However, it is not as sparse as the source file. The generated file is 27GB instead of 16GB. I can use `fallocate -d <filename>` to shrink it more. It became around 18GB. However, this operation takes quite long time. In other hand, `cp -a --sparse` can create identical file.

Also the speed is as slow as the rsync command without `--sparse`. This is [because](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/319):

> As currently designed, the --sparse option only affects writing of the destination file, not the transfer of the data

However, I am more interested in the remote size. I wonder why rsync did not replicate the exact same size of the source file as `cp --sparse=always`?

This even happens when the destination is empty. So i guess this has nothing to do with `--inplace` option.

```
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
```

according to @anx, I did some test with `--block-size=4096` which yield same file size on remote.

Comment: Is it gone with smaller --block-size? (I wonder if it is just the overhead from rsync not punching unaligned holes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sparse files significantly larger (but still sparse) after copying over a network](https://serverfault.com/questions/707786/sparse-files-significantly-larger-but-still-sparse-after-copying-over-a-networ)

Comment: @anx this does not answer my question at all. I am ok to use `--sparse` every time, and I am using backup. thus I do not use `--inplace`. My concern is more about the size of the sparse file on remote.

Comment: @anx check my update on block size